# single, double and precision

Tags: delphi

I know that storing single value (or double) can not be very precise. so storing for example 125.12 can result in 125.1200074788. now in delphi their is some usefull function like samevalue or comparevalue that take an epsilon as param and say that 125.1200074788 or for exemple 125.1200087952 is equal.

but i often see in code stuff like : if aSingleVar = 0 then ... and this in fact as i see always work. why ? why storing for exemple 0 in a single var keep the exact value ?

Comment: Zero is representable. Comparison up to a tolerance is easy enough but how do you choose the tolerance? You need to understand the algorithm. Any advice given without knowledge of the algorithm is likely bad advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only values that are in form `m*2^e`, where m and e are integers can be stored in a floating point variable (not all of them though, it depends on precision). `0` has this form, and `125.12` does not, as it equals `3128/25`, and `1/25` is not an integer power of `2`.

Comparing `125.12` to a single (or double) precision variable will most probably return always `False`, because a literal `125.12` will be treated as an extended precision number, and no single (or double) precision number would have such a value.

Comment: So it's mean that the delphi implementation of function TRectf.IsEmpty: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Right <= Left) or (Bottom <= Top);
end;

if not very accurate ?

Comment: @loki the problem is with equality of different types; here you have <= and the same types (Right, Left, Top and Bottom have the same type, I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

Storage of decimal values are done by storing the sum of: [0|1]*2^n, where n goes from +a to -b.

Examples (with a three bit storage to simplify):

```
3.5 = 1*2^1 + 1*2^0 + 1*2^-1
3.0 = 1*2^1 + 1*2^0 + 0*2^-1
2.5 = 1*2^1 + 0*2^0 + 1*2^-1
2.0 = 1*2^1 + 0*2^0 + 0*2^-1
1.5 = 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 + 1*2^-1
1.0 = 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 + 0*2^-1
0.5 = 0*2^1 + 0*2^0 + 1*2^-1
0.0 = 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 + 0*2^-1
```

But 0.3 can not be stored exactly: 0*{0.5=2^-1} + 1*{0.25=2^-2} + ... and so on to infinity, but the number of elements to add is limited. There is no sum of powers of two that gives exacly 0.3; in such example a three bit storage would store 0.3 as 1*{0.25=2^-2} + 0*{0.25=2^-3} + 1*{0.25=2^-4} = 0.3125

Hope this way is more clear why storing decimal values is imprecise by nature of storage, since storage is a sum of powers of two.

Of course, single and double have much more significant decimals than only what gives three bits, i used three bits only to clearly illustrate why decimals can not be stored exactly... not only thinking on Pi and Sqrt(2) and so on like irrational numbers, etc., that have an infinite number of decimals, also for simple rational values as 3/10 happens the same.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a good use for the BigDecimals unit by Rudy Velthuis.  Millions of decimal places of accuracy and precision.

Comment: Doesn't sound at all appropriate. Why would you think so. Have you considered the performance implications? But more importantly, how about answering the question.